# Open telemetry integration in java

Tags: java, metrics, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java, geneva-framework

I used the below command and resource for the setup of the Opentelemetry in java.
java -javaagent:path/to/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar  -Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=your-service-name -Dotel.traces.exporter=zipkin -jar myapp.jar
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation
The issue is jar file is giving issue while setup.
-- no main manifest attribute, in target/asset-upload-function-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Either some time it shows jar file is not accessible
I tried various approach available over google to implement the opentelemetry jdk but everytime i am getting the issue of jar, I added main class but it does not worked.

Comment: make sure your application jar is executable, are you able to run your jar without attaching the agent like just using the java -jar command ?